# How to connect to an HTTPS server using JIRA::Client::Automated

Tags: perl, https, jira

How can I connect to an HTTPS server using the Perl [`JIRA::Client::Automated`](https://metacpan.org/module/JIRA%3a%3aClient%3a%3aAutomated) module?

Answer (score 0):

Provide an https URL:

```
use strict;
use warnings
use JIRA::Client::Automated;

my $user = 'foo';
my $pass = 'bar';
my $url = 'https://xxx.yyy';

my $jira = JIRA::Client::Automated->new($url, $user, $pass);
```

Consider reading the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~frimicc/JIRA-Client-Automated-1.04/lib/JIRA/Client/Automated.pm), or at least stating what problems you had when you tried.